# VideoChat Application

Tags: java, webcam

Hey I have a program written exclusively in Java where users can make a username-password account where they send messages to a server that then sends messages back to according users kind of like an AIM or Skype chatroom. I want to have a videochat option, but I have no clue how to go about doing it. Should I have users directly connect to other users over a TCP connection that's attached to a video stream or have it sort of echo back the same way that the messages are sent to the server then back to the clients? I have no clue could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, you should help the clients establish their own point-to-point connection, but definitely not echo back. Just imagine the amount of bandwidth you would use :D

Comment: This is good advice, your server will melt otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to consider using a selfwritten UDP based protocol for speed gain

Comment: So basically it should sporadically take pictures from your webcam and send them via a UDP port to the other computer?